# Error in function datafsm::evolve_model()

Tags: r

Getting the error given bellow with evolve_model() in R

```
library(datafsm)

res <- evolve_model(cdata, cv=FALSE)
```

We set a seed for you to make this reproducible. It is 40. If you want the same results, next time you run this with the same settings, also set the seed argument of this function to 40.

> Error in fitness(Pop[i, ], ...) : unused argument (maxfitness = 1)

Anybody help?